# Sizing an Image in CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Forgive me if this question has been asked before, but I always pull together random hacks for images and want to know a definitive way to do what I'm seeking. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="track-artwork">
      <img src="<?php echo $chart_track->image; ?>" class="background-image">
      <audio>
          <source src="" type="audio/mp4" />
          <source src="" type="audio/aac" />
      </audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image I'm linking to is 111px X 111px. It needs to be smaller to fit into the track-artwork div and be fully displayed. I do not have the ability to edit the asset's size with something like photoshop. I want to make it so the image acts as a "background" of sorts, sized to fit the "track-artwork" div with 5px of margin on either size. Here's the CSS I've toyed with to achieve this:

```
.track-artwork {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working out. The width seems to be sized properly, but the height isn't working -- it seems to stay 111px no matter what I input. I've tried it with hard pixel values, but it doesn't change. Thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the image to the div background and use either contain or cover as the background-size.

```
.track-artwork {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
    background-size: cover; // or background-size: contain;
}
```

Cover will fill the entire div with the background image, cutting off part of the image if the ratios aren't the same.

Contain will resize the image to be fully visible within the div.
You'll have to set the background-image url to the correct image location using php.

Comment: This works great except when I extend the height of the div a lot... the image doesn't stretch to fit the height of its container and is instead vertically centered...

Comment: I think that's probably better. If the image upsizes too much, then it will get really pixelated. Maybe use a `background-color` that acts as a buffer around the image when the div is extended so much?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the CSS3 `background-size` property.

**PHP**

```
<div class="track-artwork" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $chart_track->image; ?>);">
    <audio>
        <source src="" type="audio/mp4" />
        <source src="" type="audio/aac" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.track-artwork {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**IE8 Polyfill**

If you need to support IE8, there is a Polyfill. You can get it, and information on how to use it at: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill